# Using the AC97 Codec on an Atlys Spartan 6 Board

Tags: audio, fpga, verilog, spartan

I'm a beginner to FPGA programming. I just started programming an Atlys Spartan 6 board and so far have written one program to blink LEDs in a counter pattern.

Now I'm trying to send the clock signal down-sampled to audio frequencies to the AC97 codec. Here is the Verilog program I've written:

```
module music(
    input clk,
    output ac97_sdo
    );
reg [25:0] count_aud;
reg clk_aud;

assign ac97_sdo = clk_aud;

/* down-sample the 100MHz system clock to 1kHz */
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    count_aud <= count_aud + 1;
    if (50000 == count_aud)
    begin
        clk_aud <= !clk_aud;
        count_aud <= 0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

The bit-file generation is fine, but the code doesn't seem to work - I don't hear anything either on Line Out or on HP Out (I don't know how to control the output, either), and I don't have enough experience with the AC97 specification to figure this out. The audio part of the UCF is:

```
NET ac97_bitclk LOC = L13;
NET ac97_sdi LOC = T18;
NET ac97_sdo LOC = N16;
NET ac97_sync LOC = U17;
NET ac97_reset LOC = T17;
```

Do I need to use the bit clock, sync, reset, etc. to make this work? If yes, how can I go about it?

I couldn't find any detailed information on the Atlys Reference Manual.

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the IC's datasheet for clues, and use a scope on the output signals to make sure they look like what you want them to look like. BTW, you are both incrementing and resetting count_aud when it equals 50000; use 'else'.

Comment: There is a new proposal at Areas 51: [Broadcast and Media Technologies](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36807/broadcast-and-media-technologies?referrer=lxeiaDBzsJIqpGpL-P5bMg2) where we invites experts in codec development work. Please join and invite others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface to an AC97 codec is a bit more complicated than straight digital audio. The serial data consists of 256-bit data frames; each frame contains several channels of 20-bit samples. The overall data rate is 12.288 MHz; dividing by 256 gives the sample rate of 48 kHz. Part of the 256-bit frame is dedicated to control messages, e.g. to set mixer registers. You may need to do this once after power up/reset to set the volume.

The AC97 spec is available [from Intel](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/ac97_r23.pdf). Writing your own master is not unreasonable but it will take some time. You may also be able to find one you can reuse. [OpenCores has one](http://opencores.org/project,ac97). There's a very barebones AC97 controller and some general information about the protocol [here](http://www-mtl.mit.edu/Courses/6.111/labkit/audio.shtml).

I can't remember how many of the AC97 registers are standardized. The manual I found online for your board says it has an LM4550 codec. Assuming that's right, you may want to refer to the [LM4550 datasheet](http://www.national.com/opf/LM/LM4550.html) for a complete list of configuration registers.

Comment: @Icarus if you do have the LM4550 on your board, definitely check out the general information link, since it's about the same chip

Comment: Thank you, although I was hoping there might be something simpler, like holding the reset down or some such! Will check out the links!